# Java & Regular expression

Tags: java, regex, parsing

Need help with parsing line where **keywords** included in brackets `[]`.

I tried but have wrong result:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Matcher mtr = Pattern.compile("(\\w+-\\w+|\\w+)+").matcher("[foo-bar] [baz][qux]");

        if (mtr.find()) for (int i = 0; i < mtr.groupCount(); i++) {
            System.out.println(mtr.group(i));
        }
    }
}
```

### Result(wrong):

> foo-bar

### Me need:

```
foo-bar
baz
qux
```

What should be regex that parse string as on last example ?

Comment: you need to call `find()` in a loop until it stops finding.  the groups are the groups for a _single match_, not _all the matches_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply try using `String#split()` method.

```
String str = "[foo-bar] [baz][qux]";
String[] array = str.substring(1, str.length() - 1).split("\\]\\s*\\[");
```

Comment: This will leave "[" and "]" in array[0] and array[array.length - 1] which is not wanted. "[foo-bar" instead of foo-bar.

Comment: I don't think so. That's why substring is used.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    Matcher mtr = Pattern.compile("[\\w-]+").matcher("[foo-bar] [baz][qux]");
    while(mtr.find()) {
        System.out.println(mtr.group());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `if (mtr.find())`:

```
while (mtr.find())
   for (int i = 0; i < mtr.groupCount(); i++) {
      System.out.println(mtr.group(i));
   }
```

i.e. you need to call `matcher#find()` inside a loop to have global matched returned.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your brackets can't be nested, you can try the regex

```
\[([^\]]*)\]
```

and extract the first capturing group.

That is:

```
Matcher mtr = Pattern.compile("\\[([^\\]]*)\\]").matcher("[foo-bar] [baz][qux]");

while (mtr.find())
    System.out.println(mtr.group(1));
```

```
foo-bar
baz
qux
```

Answer (score 1):

try this retular expression

```
\[[^\[\]]*\]
```

http://rubular.com/r/heMGeTMjuB

alternatively, this one is similar, and will parse things such as `"[foo[bar]"` as `foo[bar`

```
\[(.*?)\]
```

http://rubular.com/r/IzPI0RcLmS